# Cant boot from ubuntu install media

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bootable-media, dualboot, rufus

I have a Surface Pro 7, currently running Windows 11 and want to install Ubuntu as a second OS. I can not get the install media, which I created using rufus on Windows 11, to boot. With the same removable media I can get a Windows installation media to boot, as well as a Arch media. I followed [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) guide to the letter. Secure Boot is turned off and booting from USB is allowed in UEFI. I've also used multiple data storage options (usb sticks, sd cards, external hard drive), which I have verified to work with other images, with the same results. The Image I am using is from the [official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), version number 22.04.4-desktop-amd64. I would be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: Unless you have heavy loads for Ubuntu, you are better off with an Ubuntu VM.   I have 4 operating systems here running simultaneously and change with the flick of a mouse. Host is Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: **Ubuntu does not require Secure Boot to be disabled and it should _never_ be disabled** - there's _no use case for this_, except for OS developers in select instances. The purpose of Secure Boot is to ensure the bootloader of an OS hasn't been compromised, such as by a rootkit. No modern OS requires Secure Boot to be disabled, as an OS not within the EFI boot certificate can be registered via the boot tab within the UEFI firmware settings. There's no reason to dual-boot unless for some reason a VM _(can be configured with RDP)_ or WSL Ubuntu won't work. Is CSM Mode disabled _(it should be)_?

Comment: After setting Secure Boot *on*, you might try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/, on the off-chance that there is some issue with the 22.04 installer.